# R: Iteration by variable

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I have the following dataset1:

```
Height | Group
1,556  |  A
2,111  |  B
1,556  |  A
2,341  |  B
1,256  |  A
2,411  |  B
```

I would like to compute shapiro wilk normality test for Height by variable Group

```
myvar <- c("Height")

res<- vector("list", length(myvars))

a <- factor(dataset1$Group)
myfactor <- levels(a)

i=1
for (myfactor in dataset1) {
    res[[i]] <- shapiro.test(dataset1$Size)
    i=i+1
}
```

res - returns n groups of tests, but all with same p-value and W.
Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to write new code than find all errors in your code.

```
lapply(split(dataset1$Height,dataset1$Group),shapiro.test)

$`  A`

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  X[[1L]] 
W = 0.75, p-value = 3.031e-08


$`  B`

       Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  X[[2L]] 
W = 0.9134, p-value = 0.4295
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is hosed is all sorts of ways.  Here are a few:

1. You create `myfactor` outside of the loop, but then you make it the iterator.
2. `dataset1` is your data (data.frame?).  I'm not even sure what `myfactor` will be inside a loop created by `for (myfactor in dataset1)`.
3. You don't subset the data sent to `shapiro.test`.
4. `myvars` isn't defined and `dataset1$Size` should probably be `dataset1$Height`.

Try this instead.

```
res <- list()
for (mf in levels(dataset1$Group)) {
    res[[mf]] <- shapiro.test(dataset1$Height[dataset1$Group == mf])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply.
For future notice:
If you wish to compute (for selected variables in a dataset) a normality test by factor:

```
variaveis <- colnames(dataset1)[c(1:2)]
/////alternative: variaveis <- c("height", "weight") 
res<- vector("list", length(variaveis))

for (i in 1:length(variaveis)) {
    #calcula o shapiro por factor para variaveis selecionadas
    res[[i]] <- lapply(split(dataset1[,variaveis[i]] ,dataset1$sex), shapiro.test)
}
res
```

PS: sex = GROUP in the previous example
Again Thanks
Wish this code helps reducing code
M.